# Unity animation tool doesn't save changes

Tags: unity, animation, rigging

I'm trying to create an animation inside Unity using the animator tool, however the record tool isn't recording my changes and I'm struggling to get this to create animations.

I have created an example here:
https://i.gyazo.com/91f88b3531b4fb3ffd4100d40f06bdcf.mp4

I have tried recreating the animation file, but no matter what I do it refuses to record the element?

Any information would be appreciated, as it appears unity may be bugged.

When applying an update between tweened keypoints the fields for X Y Z are red and do not apply changes

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to add key frames to the animation.

There is a button on the right of where it says "Samples 60", a sort of diamond with a cross hair in it this is how you add key frames.

So add one key frame at the start of the animation for what position/rotation whatever the animated object starts in (which you can see in your screen shot as the diamonds in a column)

Then add another keyframe at the end with the end value you want to animate to, obviously you can add more keyframes, I would check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimatingAGameObject.html for a better understanding.

You also dont have to record the animations as such if you wish, you could define the first key frame with a position (0,0,0) then add another key frame and set the objects position to (0,10,0) then press play and watch it animate between start and end values.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the issue, on the terms I wanted to do frame by frame changes and not tweening the Position fields show red and then refuse to save changes

Comment: I'm not sure the animator does anything without at least two key frames to be honest.

Comment: Definitely has 2 key frames: https://i.gyazo.com/81d316f0c0ab8ef58e75a2d91535d541.mp4

Comment: In the GIF you posted the position changes from 0,0,0 to 0,0,0.3 units in 1 second a change so small and quick would hardly be noticeable but it is indeed moving the entire model by 0.3? Could you update the question with what you are trying to achieve with animator on the game object?

Comment: My point is that the field is red and removes the changes. Nothing I'm doing is working, this has nothing to do with the distance amount.

Comment: Because you are running in preview mode. Disable Preview mode to make changes to the animation. (Button to the left of record)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. I got it to work using the auto keyframe recorder (the red dot button) on the Animation tab.